# csf/lfd doesn't actually block IP's

Tags: centos, firewall

I use CSF/LFD on CentOS 7 and DirectAdmin and my logfiles are filled with lines like these:

```
Mar 11 20:04:07 host kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:96:89:93:38:10:d5:70:a3:6e:08:00 SRC=104.248.133.192 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=246 ID=54321 PROTO=TCP SPT=40178 DPT=9151 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 11 20:04:13 host kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:96:89:93:38:10:d5:70:a3:6e:08:00 SRC=141.98.89.143 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=249 ID=46818 PROTO=TCP SPT=55383 DPT=4971 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 11 20:04:34 host kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:96:89:93:38:10:d5:70:a3:6e:08:00 SRC=196.52.43.60 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=248 ID=29573 PROTO=TCP SPT=56489 DPT=8088 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 11 20:04:55 host kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:96:89:93:38:10:d5:70:a3:6e:08:00 SRC=180.168.181.102 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=43 ID=4276 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46402 DPT=3306 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 11 20:04:56 host kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:96:89:93:38:10:d5:70:a3:6e:08:00 SRC=180.168.181.102 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=43 ID=4277 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=46402 DPT=3306 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Mar 11 20:04:59 host kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=ens160 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:96:89:93:38:10:d5:70:a3:6e:08:00 SRC=81.22.45.191 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=41406 PROTO=TCP SPT=42216 DPT=1902 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

As you can see, 180.168.181.102 is mentioned twice. That is because all these IP addresses aren't actually blocked and can try again and again. I have searched for a solution to this but I haven't found anything like this. 'TESTING' is set no '0' in the configfile, so it should actually act upon the detections, but clearly it doesn't.

To be clear: the problem here is that "ConfigServer Firewall & Security - lfd" does report IP's to be blocked in the syslog but when I list the iptables rules, none of these 'blocked' IP's appear in the block chain, so they are not blocked as they should have been. My syslog keeps being filled every second with IP's supposedly being blocked but no evidence is found that they truly are. I have tested this with my phone on a cellular network; my phone's IP does get listed as being blocked, but I'm still able to access my server without any problem.